# Первый раз отправляется get запрос, 2 раз нет

Tags: java, android, get, callback

```
    public interface OAuthServerIntf {

    @GET("drive/v2/files")
    Call<GDriveFiles> listFiles1(
        @Query("q") String q
    );
    }
```

**Вот, где обрабатывается запрос и при выборе элемента в списке снова запускается с новым параметром q:**

```
    private void listGDriveUserFiles(String q){
    OAuthServerIntf server=RetrofitBuilder.getOAuthClient(this);
    Call<GDriveFiles> listFilesCall=server.listFiles(q);
    listFilesCall.enqueue(new Callback<GDriveFiles>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<GDriveFiles> call, Response<GDriveFiles> response) {
            Log.e(TAG,"The call listFilesCall succeed with [code="+response.code()+" and has body = "+response.body()+" and message = "+response.message()+" ]");
            //ok we have the list of files on GDrive
            if(response.code()==200&&response.body()!=null){
                // txvResult.setText(response.body().toString());

                for (GDriveFile file : response.body().getFiles()) {
                    // txvResult.setText(txvResult.getText()+file.getName()+" ");
                    gdriveFiles.add(file);
                }
                adapter = new Data_Adapter(context, R.layout.list_item, gdriveFiles);
                txvResult.setAdapter(adapter);
                txvResult.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        GDriveFile selectedItem = gdriveFiles.get(position);
                        listGDriveUserFiles(selectedItem.getId());
                    }
                });


            }else if(response.code()==400){

            }else if(response.code()==401){

            }else if(response.code()==403){

            }else if(response.code()==404){

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<GDriveFiles> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG,"The call listFilesCall failed",t);
        }
    });
}
```

В первый раз запрос обрабатывается, а второй раз проходит Callback метод и выходит полностью из метода. ***Используется GOOGLE API***. В чем причина?

Comment: Второго вызова  коде не видать

Comment: Вызов этого метода по клику в списке. Все работает, просто запрос долго обрабатывается

Comment: Т.е. проблема не в том, что не работает, а втом что медленно запрос исполняется?

Comment: Точнее я в дебаге запускал и в дебаге он проходил callback ,когда запускал сначала метода . Код рабочий , все работает) не в дебаг режиме все выполняется довольно быстро

Comment: Может быть вы знаете как лучше организовать проход по папкам Гугл драйв? Сделать стэк и запоминать предыдущую папку , от которой был осуществлён переход . Или есть какой-то другой более эффективный способ?

Comment: Никогда этим не занимался - ничего сказать не могу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод, в принципе, работает . Нужно очищать gdriveFiles перед заполнение в него данными. Тогда все будет наглядно видно.

Встречный вопрос: как лучше организовать проход по папкам Гугл драйв? Сделать для этого стэк и записывать в него id предыдущей папки, от которой был осуществлён переход. Или есть какой-то более эффективный способ?